# Simplify two if statements

Tags: java

I have this piece of code I am trying to clean up and refactor

```
  if (i.startsWith("/") || i.startsWith("~~")) {

            int s = 1;

            if (i.startsWith("~~")) {
                s = 2;
            }
            i= i.substring(s);
        }
```

this is messy since there is two if statements and hard to read. Is there a way I can refactor?

Comment: it  also doesn´t make sense, as if either `i.startsWith("/") || i.startsWith("~")` is true, `i.startsWith("!")` can never be true.

Comment: Simplifying this code is very simple: drop the inner `if`, because its condition is guaranteed to be false.

Comment: Use a `if-else if` clause or better yet a `switch` statement.

Comment: I have edited the question as i made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a simple snippet like this I’d do:

```
    if (i.startsWith("/")) {
        i = i.substring(1);
    } else if (i.startsWith("~~")) {
        i = i.substring(2);
    }
```

If there were four or five or more different prefixes to strip, I’d invent something more generic.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the fact that it looks like you´re just trying to find out how the `String` does start and remove that part if it starts with it, you could just use a single regex to begin with.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(test("~~TestAbc"));
    System.out.println(test("/TestAbc"));
    System.out.println(test("TestAbc"));
}

private static String test(String i) {
    return i.replaceAll("^/|^~~", "");
}
```

O/P

```
TestAbc
TestAbc
TestAbc
```